# Problema ao realizar checkout em branch - Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Criei uma branch no bitbucket e não consigo fazer o checkout na mesma. O comando que normalmente utilizo é:

git fetch && git checkout

Digito o comando no terminal local e simplesmente ele efetua o checkout na branch, continua na master.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam que continuo no "ramo" master. 
Tentei fazer isso em estações diferentes e acontece a mesma coisa.

Branchs no bitbucket:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentou fazer o pull tambem?

Comment: Sim, diz que já está atualizado.
root@Fred:/var/www/html/gseg/gseg# git pull
| Password for 'https://fredericobinsfeld@bitbucket.org':  | 
Already up-to-date.

Comment: O branch consegue ser listado pelo git? Se sim, é algo bem estranho :/

Comment: Parece que o `fetch` retornou erro. `git fetch; echo $?` retorna 0 ou outra coisa?

Comment: SIm, o branch está criado no bitbutcket Paulo. Inseri uma imagem ali na pergunta.. Mas no git status não aparece, tem alguma outra forma de verificar?

Comment: Jeferson, não encontrei onde retornou o erro do fetch.

Comment: Criei uma nova brach agora com o nome "teste", deu certo. Acho que o problema está em utilizar o underline. Não sabia que não podia utilizar. Procede?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dá um "git status" pra ver se tem algum arquivo sem commitar, o git não vai deixar vc dar checkout com arquivos sem commitar. 
Outra dica é vc apenas dar o git checkout,a sequencia de comandos "git fetch && git checkout acoes_criminosas" impede que o segundo comando seja executado caso o primeiro dê erro.